# Basic design pattern in simple games

Tags: oop, design-patterns, singleton

I'm considering this design pattern for a simple iOS tic-tac-toe game:

- `GameState` singleton class that keeps track of X and O locations on the board
- `GameDisplay` singleton class that handles the display of the board and the touch events

This separation of state and display seems reasonable imo. `GameDisplay` can forward taps on the board to `GameState` where the board is updated and winning conditions are checked. `GameState` can in turn tell `GameDisplay` to draw another X/O or that the game is complete and who the winner is. My current plan is to use methods like `GameState.playAtSquare(Square s)` to communicate between the two singletons.

**Does this design fall victim to any major downsides of using singletons?** iirc there's some controversy over using singleton classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I argue that you should **not** use a Singleton in this case.

Use an object to represent `GameState` (or `Game`), as it enables you to allow for (for instance) multiple games at once.

The `GameDisplay` should be a [**single instance object**, which is different than a **Singleton**.](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/40373/so-singletons-are-bad-then-what) The `GameDisplay` object should be passed to methods which needs it through [**Dependency Injection**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).

Answer (score 1):

There will still be dependencies and potential threading issues (if you do not take preventative measures).

It most cases a singleton can be avoided, and in this case it can be also.  Instead, what don't you pass around a reference to `GameState` and `GameDisplay`? Rather than it being a singleton and live the lifetime of the application, you can have the two classes be contained in something such as a `GameApplication` class.

If you do it that way, then you avoid `GameState` and `GameDisplay` from being singletons, as they do not necessarily need to be one.

For an example of handling game states without singletons, take a look at [Gamestate management without evil Singletons](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/27272/gamestate-management-without-evil-singletons).

Comment: You don't explain why Singletons are evil. Please see: http://www.slideshare.net/kktv/how-is-a-paradigm-created

Comment: This is because I assume the poster knows the evils of a singleton, which if he is helping to avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

The downside of singletons anywhere are the same as the downside of global variables;  that is, some object in your program which has a state is directly accessible and modifiable from anywhere else in your program.

What it means to your design is that you're building rigidity into your program by making the bold assumption that you can never use a different kind of GameState or a different kind of GameDisplay, because the rest of your program is likely to be dependent on the existence of those singletons.

Problems often arise from this situation after the singleton has been "welded" into the program - any later changes to GameState and GameDisplay may have unintentional knock-on effects to the rest of your program, and finding "workarounds" to limit or stop the effect of those changes might lead to ugly/hacky solutions elsewhere in your code.

There's almost always a preferable alternative to singletons.   While some people are tempted by singletons because it involves "doing a bit less typing up-front", once your program starts to grow a little, it nearly always ends up being a source of unnecessary complexity, special cases and quirks.